# How to parse mailchimp action url using php?

Tags: php

I'm working on a custom mailchimp form. So I only need action url from this mailchimp code.

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->       
<form action="//xxxxx.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a79fe811eb786b41111be6f4c&id=41b3b956f1" method="post">  
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Can anyone tell me how to parse it using php without depending on third party parsing library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More robust approach

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

    <form action="//xxxxx.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=a79fe811eb786b41111be6f4c&id=41b3b956f1" method="post">

    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->');
$form = $doc->getElementsByTagName("form")->item(0);
$url = $form->getAttribute('action');
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to do, but look at [parse_url](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). To parse the query (what's after the question mark), use [parse_str](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php).